# PDF Scrolling format...?

Tags: pdf, scroll, pdf-generation, acrobat

I'm a graphic designer and I'm making a presentation and exporting it to a pdf. 
What I'm trying to achieve is a PDF that when opened is viewed at 100%, and all the user does is scroll down the PDF to view the rest of the design. 
My fear is that when I create the PDF it will appear zoomed out on the screen when the user opens it, which is what I don't want. I've created this test doc and taken screenshots to show you guys what I mean.

[Desired effect when doc is opened](https://imageshack.com/i/n1lxy9p)

[Not what I want](https://imageshack.com/i/mvmwgbp)

Thanks a lot for your help guys I really appreciate it

Lisle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the opening zoom factor and whether the toolbars and other window elements are shown in the Document Properties in Acrobat, in the Initial View tab.